# Is $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L_\infty(0,1)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, function-spaces

I know that $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L_p(0,1)$ for any $1\le p<\infty$. However, I haven't seen anything about $L_\infty$. Is $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L_\infty(0,1)$?

Comment: Every separable Banach space embeds into $L_{\infty}(0,1)$.

Comment: Even into $C([0,1])$ (known to Banach--p. 185 in my copy of his monograph).

Comment: @bathalf15320  MANY Thx!

Comment: @Mateusz Wasilewski  Many thx